# how can I update set to add full url to column?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have delete the url from my table my url look like this before the delete:

`www.anyURL.com/wow/page.aspx`

after delete are `page.aspx page` I have 190 records, how can I add url `www.anyURL.com/wow/` to my records?

Comment: Can you please be more specific? Are you saying that you want every row in the table to be prefixed with `www.anyURL.com/wow/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE [table]
SET URL_FIELD = 'www.anyURL.com/wow/' + URL_FIELD
```

Not sure if the above is what you are looking for, let  me know if you need more than that.

As Aaron Bertarnd says if you need a filter. :

```
UPDATE [table]
SET URL_FIELD = 'www.anyURL.com/wow/' + URL_FIELD
WHERE URL_FIELD NOT LIKE 'www.anyURL.com/wow/'
```

Comment: Probably want a filter, in case "after delete" did not change the entire table, e.g. `WHERE URL_Column NOT LIKE 'www.anyURL.com%'` or maybe even less specific.